# Solid of Revolution using Disk or Washer Method

Tags: calculus, solid-of-revolution

Find the volume of the solid generated by revolving the region bounded by the parabola $\frac{-x^2}{4}$ and the line $y=-1$ about the following lines.

$y = -1,
y = -2,
y = 1$

***I am struggling to understand the setup when the line to revolve around is not directly on the x or y axis.  I am not looking for anyone to solve the integral, I just need help with setup for $\left[R\left(x\right)\right]$ and $\left[r\left(x\right)\right]$***

$V = \int_{-2}^2 \pi\left(\left[R\left(x\right)\right]^2-\left[r\left(x\right)\right]^2\right)dx$

Set up for $y = -1$

***Since the first revolution is being revolved around the same axis as the lower boundary. I'm no sure if I can just use Disk Method only, but I know I need to account for the -1 offset.***

***I would assume the radii is***
$\left[R\left(x\right)\right] = -1 - \frac{-x^2}{4}$

Set up for $y = -2$

Set up for $y = 1$

***Thanks in advance for any support you can give***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the following figure, the coordinate axes have deliberately been omitted so that one can concentrate on the essentials.

[image: Solid of Revolution by annulus]

The upper green region is rotated about the horizontal axis of revolution
$$ y=a $$
which does not pass through the figure. Note that $a$ could be positive or negative.

The figure is bounded between the graphs of

\begin{eqnarray}
y&=&f(x)\text{ and}\\
y&=&g(x)
\end{eqnarray}
with $y=f(x)$ the **farthest** from the axis of revolution and $y=g(x)$ the **closest**.

Then the outer radius will always be

$$ R=\vert f(x)-a \vert $$

and the inner radius will always be

$$ r=\vert g(x)-a \vert $$

and the volume of the solid of revolution will be

$$ \pi\int (R^2-r^2)\,dx $$

between appropriate limits of integration.